# Change default @html.DisplayNameFor

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

guys. I've been thinking. I'm making a table based on a database column. So, by default, asp.net gave (for example) :

```
@html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FULL_NAME);
```

But then it would displayed it just like that. Are there anyways to change the display in the view to "Full Name" or "Name", maybe?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just add the `[Display(Name = "Full Name")]` attribute to your property

Comment: Hi, Stephen. Thanks for still wanting to help me.

Comment: I've tried. But, it won't budge. I mean, it doesn't change

Comment: Of course it works - show what you have tried

Comment: I tried to use [DisplayName = ("Full Name")]. But, it appears to be wrong. And your advice works perfectly. Thanks, bro!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[Display]` in the model

```
public class User
{
   [Display(Name = "Name")]
   public string FULL_NAME;
}
```

Comment: There is no `DisplayName()` extension method that accepts 2 parameters

Comment: It says the name 'model' does not exist in the current context.. I tried to change with LabelFor or such, it's even worse. It would tell that my table does not contain a definition for 'FULL_NAME'..

Comment: The `DisplayAttribute` will not work with fields (only properties)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. I wrote [DisplayName = ("Full Name")]

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FULL_NAME, "Name")
```